# Batch command that automatically deletes a folder

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I want to delete my folder `C:/gametemp` because my game creates that folder automatically and won't run unless I delete the folder. Is there a way to write a batch file that will check for the folder in a loop and delete it automatically?

OS: Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

/S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
        in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
        tree.

/Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
```

This is the general procedure used in command prompt to delete a directory and it's subdirectories.

1. Make a batch file on your computer.
2. Write above command with specified path
3. Create Schedule Task for the batch file.